# How do I show this function is convex?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

I cannot figure out how to show this function is convex. When I twice differentiate it the hessian does not have positive diagonal values and it shows as concave. I know it has both a concave and convex part of the graph as I have plotted, so how do I show the convex part?

$$f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x+y}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax. You can learn more at: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint (without Hessian matrix otherwise see [Convexity, Hessian matrix, and positive semidefinite matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1704131/convexity-hessian-matrix-and-positive-semidefinite-matrix)).

Note that for $t\in (0,1)$, and for $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in D_+:=\{(x,y): x+y>0\}$ (which is a convex set),
$$f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2,ty_1+(1-t)y_2)-tf(x_1,y_1)-(1-t)f(x_2,y_2)\\=
\frac{t(1-t)(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2}{(x_1+y_1)(x_2+y_2)(tx_1+(1-t)x_2+ty_1+(1-t)y_2)}\geq 0.$$
What about $D_-:=\{(x,y): x+y<0\}$? What may we conclude?

Answer (score 0):

HINT

you have ti find the points where |H| is positive definite